# Bayes statistics precisely formulated

Tags: pr.probability, bayesian-probability

I am trying to learn something about Bayesian statistics, however, I am struggling already with the simplest equations and, moreover, with the very basic questions: What are we given? What is our goal?

As far as I understood the most basic setup we are given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, a space with $\sigma$-algebra $(V, \mathcal{B})$ and a random variable $X : \Omega \to V$ which has a density parametrized by $\lambda$, $f(x;\lambda)$ and we also assume that $\lambda$ itself is drawn from a random variable $\Lambda : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Moreover we are given an observation $x$ and try to figure out something about $\lambda$ from this observation.

Then people usually write down something like
  $$p(\lambda|x) = \frac{p(x|\lambda) p(\lambda)}{p(x)}$$

The expressions above are then evaluated to

$$p(x|\lambda) = f(x;\lambda)$$
    $$p(\lambda) = g(\lambda)$$

Question 1: What is the meaning of '$p$'?
I can hardly believe that these are probabilities, because although one could give $P(X=x|\Lambda=\lambda)$ a useful meaning [as the factorization of the conditional expected function $E(1_{X = x} | \sigma(\Lambda))$], the symbol $p(\lambda|x) = P(\Lambda=\lambda|X=x)$ would somehow still be zero all the time (as $\Lambda$ is continuously valued). So I assume that these are supposed to be densities.

Question 2: What is $X$? Isnt it merely true that we have a function $\tilde{X} : \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ [not even jointly measurable] with the property that for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed, $X_\lambda := \tilde{X}(\cdot, \lambda)$ is a random variable with density $f(\cdot; \lambda)$? Or are we considering $X(\omega) = \tilde{X}(\omega, \Lambda(\omega))$? If so, why is this measurable?

Question 3: If $p(\cdot)$ is supposed to be a density, what random variables do we put inside $p(x|\lambda)$? I assume that its supposed to be the conditional density of $X_\lambda$ and $\Lambda$. But here is the question: can one define conditional density of two random variables without the two random variables being jointly distributed? I know that one can put $f_Y(y|X=x) = \frac{f_{(X, Y)}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ but are the two random variables $X_\lambda$ and $\Lambda$ jointly distributed? This seems like an unnatural assumption...

Question 4: I guess that even if one can define conditional densities of random variables even if they are not jointly distributed then $p(x|\lambda)$ is some kind of abstract definition, so why is that the simple term $f(x;\lambda)$?

I am sorry if these are very basic questions but all the resources I was able to find skip over all these details, so pointers are very welcome :-)

Comment: Is my answer  at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187379/probability-spaces-involved-in-using-bayesian-inference of any help?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Yes, that is more or less the answer I was looking for, thanks :-) I reformulated it in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: this refers to the situation described in these [lecture notes](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~feres/Math450Lect02.pdf), where Bayes theorem is applied to events. It seems this is not what the OP has in mind, so I'm just leaving my answer for the record.*

**• What are we given?** As described in the [lecture notes](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~feres/Math450Lect02.pdf) (section 1.3), we start from the probability space $(\Omega,{\cal A},P)$. *Both* $x$ and $\lambda$ are *events* $\in{\cal A}$ and $p(x|\lambda)=p(x\cap \lambda)/p(\lambda)$ is the *probability* (not probability density) of event $x$ given event $\lambda$ (defined if $p(\lambda)\neq 0$). Bayes theorem then follows directly from 
$$p(x|\lambda)p(\lambda)=p(x\cap\lambda)=p(\lambda|x)p(x),$$
provided both $p(\lambda)$ and $p(x)$ are $\neq 0$.

The key to this precise formulation of Bayes theorem is to treat $x$ and $\lambda$ on the same footing. Both are events in ${\cal A}$, governed by the same probability $p$ of any event in ${\cal A}$ occuring, and the random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow V$ plays the same role for both $x$ and $\lambda$. So $p(x|\lambda)$ is not some kind of abstract object, but directly obtained as the ratio of the probabilities that the joined event $x\cap\lambda$ happens and the probability that the event $\lambda$ happens. Both these events are in $\cal A$, so this ratio is well defined (assuming $p(\lambda)\neq 0$).

**• What is our goal?** To appreciate the usefulness of this equation, a simple but familiar example might help. You receive an email message in ALL-CAPS. What is the probability that it is spam? You have at your disposal a collection of spam messages from the past few years, and from that you can easily determine the fraction of those message written in capital letters. The fraction is $p(\lambda|x)$, with $x$ the event "I received a spam email" and $\lambda$ the event "the email I received contains only capital letters". If you know, or can estimate, what fraction $p(x)$ of your emails is spam and what fraction $p(\lambda)$ is in all-caps, then Bayes' formula tells you the probability $p(x|\lambda)$ that a message in all-caps is spam. This is how spam filters work.

Comment: What is $P(\lambda)$ then? Is it $P(\Lambda=\lambda)$? Then its almost always zero as $\Lambda$ is continuously valued and we can throw away Bayes because the expressions do not make sense... ? Or let me formulate it that way: If you were right then $p(\lambda|x)$ was zero all the time and we would learn the expression '0' from the data...

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand... $x$ and $\lambda$ are not events, they are elements of the sets $V$ and $\mathbb{R}$... Are you talking about $[\Lambda=\lambda]$ (a zero set in $\Omega$!) ?

Comment: *** WHAT IS $p(\lambda)?$ *** If it is $P[\Lambda=\lambda]$ then it ***IS*** zero... almost always! So we cannot apply the classical Bayes! Phrased differently, if you have a normally distributed random variable $X$, what is the probability that $X$ attains the value $3.79856$? It is zero!

Comment: Bayes' theorem as formulated above (from section 1.3 in the linked notes) refers to events that do not have measure zero, for example, $1<x<3$ is an event but not $x=1$. It is also possible to formulate Bayes' theorem for continuous variables, when the probabilities have to be replaced by probability densities, see section 3.3 in the linked notes.

Comment: So we cannot apply Bayes as $\lambda$ is not an event ($P[\Lambda=\lambda] = 0$)... but we still do it... why are we allowed to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Let $(\tilde{\Omega}, \tilde{\mathcal{A}})$ be a space with $\sigma$-algebra and let $(V, \mathcal{B}, P_V), (W, \mathcal{C}, P_W)$ be probability spaces.
Let further $f : V \times W \to \mathbb{R}$ be in $L^1(V \times W)$ where $V \times W$ is endowed with 
the product sigma algebra $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{C}$ and let $g : W \to \mathbb{R}$ be in $L^1(W)$.
Assume further that $f , g > 0$ (i.e. for every $x \in V, \theta \in W, f(x,\theta) > 0$ and $g(\theta) > 0$) and that for every fixed $\theta \in W$, $\int_V f(v, \theta) d\theta = 1$ 
(i.e. $f(\cdot, \theta)$ is a density) and that $\int_W g(\theta) d\theta = 1$ (i.e. $g$ is a density).

Let $X : \tilde{\Omega} \to V,~~ \Theta : \tilde{\Omega} \to W$ be measurable maps.
We consider the (measurable!) map $(X, \Theta) : \tilde{\Omega} \to V \times W,~~ (X, \Theta)(\omega) = (X(\omega), \Theta(\omega))$.
We put $\Omega := \tilde{\Omega}, \mathcal{A} := \sigma(X \times \Theta) := (X \times \Theta)^{-1}(\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{C})$
and define a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ by
  $$P((X \times \Theta)^{-1}(U)) = \int_U f(x, \theta) g(\theta) d(x,\theta)$$
Notice that this definition makes sense as $(x, \theta) \mapsto f(x, \theta)g(\theta) \in L^1(V \times W)$ by Fubini!

Now we have the final probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and a jointly distributed random variable $(X, \Theta) : \Omega \to (V \times W)$. By means of the projections $\pi_1 : V \times W \to V, \pi_1(v, w) = v$ and $\pi_2 : V \times W, \pi_2(v, w) = w$ we obtain back the measurable maps we started with as $X = \pi_1 \circ (X, \Theta) ~\text{and}~ \Theta = \pi_2 \circ (X, \Theta)$.
Since we endowed $\Omega$ with a probability measure we can now really say that $X, \Theta$ are random variables.
Observe that we easily verify that $\Theta$ has density $g$ (For every set $C \in C$ we have
\begin{align*}
  P[\Theta \in C] &= P[\pi_2 \circ (X, \Theta) \in C] \\
   &= P[(X, \Theta) \in V \times C] \\
  &= \int_{V \times C} f(x,\theta)g(\theta) d(x,\theta) \\
  &= \int_C \int_V f(x,\theta) dx g(\theta) d\theta \\
  &= \int_C 1\cdot g(\theta) d\theta
\end{align*}
)
but it is completely unclear what density $X$ has, $X$ is just some random variable with 'unknown' distribution. Well, it is absolutely not unknown as $(X, \Theta)$ are jointly distributed but the density of $X$ is not 
interesting for us:
Let us be very concrete here and choose fixed real numbers $\alpha, \beta$,
let $\Theta$ be Beta$(\alpha, \beta)$ distributed and let $X$ be Bernoulli$(\theta)$
distributed. Encoded, this means that
\begin{align*}
  V &=\{0,1\},\\ 
 W &= (0,1), \\
 f(x,\theta) &= \theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}, \\
 \tilde{g}(\theta) &= \text{Beta}(\theta|\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \theta^{\alpha - 1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1}, \\
 g(\theta) &= \frac{1}{\int_{(0,1)} \tilde{g}(\theta)}\tilde{g}(\theta)
\end{align*}
(the nasty constant will be just as uninteresting as the other ones, see below).
Put $d := p(x) = f_X(x)$ then after doing the computation
  $$p(\lambda|x) = \frac{p(x|\lambda)p(\lambda)}{p(x)} = \text{const.} \theta^{x+\alpha-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-x}$$
i.e. we know that $p(\lambda|x)$ is a density and we know that (up to a constant) it is a Beta distribution again! Since two densities that coincide up to a constant must be the same, it must be *the* (renormalized to the interval $(0,1)$) Beta distribution (somewhat independent of what the actual value of $f_X(x)$ was)!

As $(X, \Theta)$ are jointly distributed, there is a conditional density $f_{X|\Theta}$ given by
\begin{align*}
  f_{X|\Theta}(x,\theta) &= \frac{f_{(X, \theta)}(x, \theta)}{f_\Theta(\theta)} \\
   &= \frac{h(x, \theta)}{f_\Theta(\theta)} \\
  &= \frac{f(x, \theta) g(\theta)}{g(\theta)} \\
  &= f(x, \theta)
\end{align*}
This is the key point of confusion:

Although the Bayesian people claim that one models the density of $X$ somehow, 
what they actually mean is that they model the conditional density $f_{X|\Theta} = f$
and 'computing' the density $p(x|\lambda)$ does not actually mean that they compute something 
but that they compute beforehand that the conditional density is just $f$ and insert the definition of $f$!